# После обновления win10 не отображается поле ввода пароля для входа в учетную запись

Tags: windows, windows-10

После сегодняшнего (10.04.18) обновления win10 не отображается аватарка и поле ввода пароля для входа в учетную запись, только стартовая заставка со временем и датой, тупо никуда не могу войти. Как решить эту проблему? Как откатить это обновление?

Comment: Пуск и панель пуска не отображается тоже?

Comment: Нет, только фоновая картинка

Comment: Через безопасный режим зайди и откати обнавление

Comment: Что переустановить? Учётку или ОС?

Answer (score 1):

Следует во включенной операционной системе зажать клавишу [Shift] и выбрать из меню выключения компьютера опцию «Перезагрузка» (Restart), а потом на экране загрузки последовательно нажать еще несколько кнопок.

Удаление обновлений Windows

Загрузив Windows, откройте окно «Программы и компоненты» (Programs and Features) и нажмите в левой части окна ссылку «Просмотр установленных обновлений» (View installed updates). Можно также ввести эти ключевые слова прямо в строке поиска меню «Пуск» (Start) или на начальном экране, если вам так удобнее.

Как откатить или удалить проблемное обновление Windows

Выберите в списке проблемное обновление и нажмите кнопку «Удалить» (Uninstall).

Как откатить или удалить проблемное обновление Windows

Можно выделить любое обновление и деинсталлировать его кнопкой «Удалить».

Если вы не знаете точно, какое обновление привело к возникновению проблем, посмотрите на дату установки. Можно нажать на стрелке в графе «Установлено» (Installed On) и задать диапазон дат – это поможет выявить проблемное обновление.

Как откатить или удалить проблемное обновление Windows

Определившись, просто выделите и удалите обновление, как описано выше.

[Источник](http://www.winblog.ru/quicktip/1147769788-26150101.html#sel=8:30,14:9)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Зайди в параметры -> Учетные записи -> Создать аватар 
 Введите фото или сделайте его на месте!!
```

Comment: Вы не поняли, меня не беспокоит отсутствие аватарки. После обновления, пропало поле для ввода пароля при входе в учетную запись

Comment: Ну тогда переустанови её